# How to stop PHP script in case the internet didn't work only for the AJAX response

Tags: php, ajax

I am calling the server via AJAX and I get the response of the server by checking the XmlHttp object properties like:

```
if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
    if(xmlHttp.status==200){ // AJAX succeeded }
}
```

Now, I have a timeout mechanism to wait for 10 seconds using:

```
setTimeout();
```

in Javascript for the request to be executed, in case I didn't get the status 200 for the request, then I abort the request via:

```
xmlHttp.abort()
```

and then I show a timeout message and I show a button to resend this request.

The AJAX request works perfect in 98% of time but:

The problem when my internet is shaking, I send the request successfully but when the response tries to come back, the internet doesn't work well and I lose the response, so in this case the timeout message will be triggered to user (**request not completed, please try again**) but actually in the server side (PHP), the request is executed successfully and this request is attached to email to be sent to user, so the user will get the email that the request is done but also a timeout message is seen for the user.

So what shall I do? When internet is off completely, timeout mechanism works fine! But when the ISP has such internet problem (shaking quickly), how can I do to prevent the PHP from executing?

Thanks for your help

Comment: there's nothing you can do, really. your incoming network link is down, so you cannot get ANY information about how much of your request has reached the server, or been processsed.

Comment: @MarcB What about [`connection_aborted()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php)? Surely this requires the php to sequentially check this method, but it *should* work.

Comment: not particularly useful. the server may already have finished all of the processing and stuff the "a-ok" response onto the wire. if that wire has been severed somewhere, that's not the server's fault and it wouldn't be able to recall the email it just sent.

Comment: Thanks for comments. I had a hope that there might be a solution :(

Answer (score 2):

You should leave as is , unless it is of critical importance to achieve this redundancy.

In case it is critical :

Instead of immediately throwing an error message, you could retry to send the request 2 or 3 times. This would give the server more chances to respond to the request.

To do that, you'd have to make sure that the same request isn't processed more then once (in your case sending the mail) - you'd have to implement a simple system in your php to cache responses and recognize requests that were already fulfilled so they wont be processed again.

Create an unique id in javascript and send it as a parameter in your ajax.
Use a session array to store the responses of your requests, keyed by this unique id.
When a request come in, check the responses array to see if it was already fulfilled, in which case you just echo back the cached response without processing.